# ¿Hay alguna forma de filtrar datos desde la bd usando Datatables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, pdo

Por ejemplo cuando inicializo la tabla me trae no mas los 10 últimos registros.

¿Esta seria la mejor forma de optimizar las consultas y carga de datos?.

Pero como hago que cuando se filtre por el buscador consulte directamente a la *bd* atreves de *Ajax* y si encuentra datos que coinciden con ese buscador, entonces los muestre en la tabla y quite los registros que habían, y que si no se busca nada o se limpiar el valor del buscador, vuelva y se cargue los datos iniciales.

Para eso también debe pintar los botones de editar y eliminar en la tabla, no sé cual sea la mejor manera para estar filtrando información desde la *bd*, usando *datatables*.

Necesito hacer esto mismo en *Ajax*, usando *datatables*.

```
<?php
    $item = null;
    $valor= null;

    $DTStable1 = Mdltable1::ctrMostratabl1($item, $valor);
    $fila=-1;

    foreach ($DTStable1 as $key => $value) {
        echo '<tr id="filaInsEv'.($key+1).'" class="fila-white">

            <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
            <td style="color: #305d86;">'.$value["fecha_regist"].'</td>
            <td>'.$value["fk_persona_resp"].'</td>';

            $item = "cod_item_table1";
            $valor= $value["fk_lote"];

            $referencia = Mdltable2::ctrMostrartable2($item, $valor);

            echo '<td>'.$referencia["lote_pikutable2"].'</td>
                <td>'.$referencia["viajetable2"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_pluma"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_traque"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_buch"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_proventricul"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_buche_alimen"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_pulmone"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_hematoma"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_granulom"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_dermatiti"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_viscera_roj"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_viscera_blanc"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_cloac"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_materia_feca"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["presencia_hie"].'</td>
                <td>'.$referencia["hora_sacritable2"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["hr_fin_evisceradov"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["tiemp_sacrifi"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["cloro_resi_ini_iv"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["cloro_resi_fin_iv"].'</td>'
            ;

            $item = "cod_persona_responsable_pr";

            $valor= $_SESSION["id"];

            $usuarios2 = ControladorUsuario::ctrMostrarUsuario($item, $valor);

            if($usuarios2["tipo_user"]=="ADMI"){

                echo
                    '<td>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btnEdittable1 manito-clic" editItemtable1="'.$value["cod_table1"].'" idUsuario="'.$usuarios2["cod_persona_res"].'" User="'.$usuarios2["user"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditable1"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btnDeletetable1 manito-clic" deletetable1="'.$value["cod_ptable1"].'" lotepiku="'.$referencia["lote_p"].'" viajepiku="'.$referencia["viaje"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </td>'
                ;

            }

        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

Agradecería sus ayudas, porque como lo tengo actualmente se están trayendo todos los datos, y sé que a futuro sería un problema, porque cuando tengas muchos datos, la pagina demoraría demasiado en cargar.

Comment: osea es que estoy trayendo todos los registros, es decir si hay 1000 datos mil datos me muetsra de una, u lo que quier es traer exactamente lo que se necesita, por ejemplo, los 10 ulimos registros, y depues por el filtrado traer lo que el usuario necesite, no sé si me hago entender. pero esto usando datatbles, para no peder las funciones que ofrece.

Comment: el problema de ese ejemplo, es que yo tengo tablas relacionados, por ejemplo, guardo el id el la tablasegundaria, y en php hago una consulta a la tabla de datos, para en vez de mostrar el id, mostrar el nombre que correponde a ese id, y el metodo que he visto realmente es confuso para mi.

Comment: entonces por es mimso necesito algo que se acople con mis metodos, gracias.

Comment: actualice mi codigo php, donde muestro como traigo los datos de las tablas que estan relacioanas, y es algo similar que necesito hacer atrabes de ajax, cuando se filtre informacion, para poder mostrar los datos correctamente.

Comment: Creo que lo más adecuado sería crear los encabezados de la tabla y enviar un [JSON con todos los resultados](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) para que _Datatables_ genere el contenido. De esta forma, descargas toda la información una sola vez y tienes todas las funcionalidades que necesites (buscar, ordenar, paginar, etc.)

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo usando mi metodos?

Comment: ¿Cuál método? Edita la pregunta para mostrar cómo activas _Datatables_

Comment: quiero decir usando el mismo me todo que uso para mostrar los datos de la bd por ejemplo: $referencia = Mdltable2::ctrMostrartable2($item, $valor); y convertir esos datos json y así  cargarlos directamente.